# translation entry in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I have the following reference:

> V.L. Ginzburg and L.D. Landau, Zh. Eksp. Teor. Fiz. **20** (1950) 1064

which was translated in:

> L. D. Landau, *Collected papers* (Oxford: Pergamon Press, 1965) 546

Is there a good way to make an (one?) entry in a `bib(la)tex` file that gives something similar to:

> V.L. Ginzburg and L.D. Landau, Zh. Eksp. Teor. Fiz. **20** (1950) 1064; English translation: L. D. Landau, *Collected papers* (Oxford: Pergamon Press, 1965) 546

There is a `translator` field in `biblatex`, but it is not enough, since year, magazine etc. are different, too.

My solution so far is `\cite[][English translation: L. D. Landau, Collected papers (Oxford: Pergamon Press, 1965) 546]{citekeyoriginal}`. Is there a better way? I am using the `numeric-comp` biblatex style.

Comment: We'll need to know which `biblatex` style you use.

Comment: I use the `numeric-comp` style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not able to provide a perfect solution, but I would use a `\fullcite` in the `addendum` field. In order to suppress the translation in the bibliography (so that it does not appear twice), you could use `options = {skipbib=true}`, if that is desired. Here is a MWE (note that you have to run biber (or BibTeX) twice, since the \fullcite can only be resolved in the second run):

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{G-L1950,
  author = {Ginzburg, V. L. and Landau, L. D.},
  title = {A title},
  journaltitle = {Zh. Eksp. Teor. Fiz.},
  date = {1950},
  volume = {20},
  pages = {1064},
  addendum = {English translation: \fullcite[546]{L1965}}
}
@book{L1965,
  author = {Landau, L. D.},
  title = {Collected Papers},
  location = {Oxford},
  publisher = {Pergamon Press},
  date = {1965},
  options = {skipbib=true}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=numeric-comp,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{G-L1950}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would indeed call it the perfect solution (for me :)

Comment: Really great solution! +1

Comment: Brilliant! Note that I'm personally leaning towards keeping the translated title in square brackets right after the original title (the standard way to do that) and thus I don't give the translation entry a title so that it's not repeated.